# Conv3d: InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): Input to reshape is a tensor

Tags: python, tensorflow, reshape, convolution

```
 inp = tf.expand_dims(inp, -1)
    conv = tf.layers.conv3d(inputs=inp, filters=64, kernel_size=[5, 5, 5], padding='same', activation=tf.nn.relu)
    print 'conv size', conv.get_shape().as_list()
    pool = tf.layers.max_pooling3d(inputs=conv, pool_size=[2, 2, 2], strides=2)
    print 'pool size', pool.get_shape().as_list()
    conv2 = tf.layers.conv3d(inputs=pool, filters=32, kernel_size=[5, 5, 5], padding='same', activation=tf.nn.relu)
    print 'conv size', conv2.get_shape().as_list()
    pool2 = tf.layers.max_pooling3d(inputs=conv2, pool_size=[2, 2, 2], strides=5)
    print 'pool size', pool2.get_shape().as_list()
    flattened = tf.reshape(pool2, [-1, 10, 1 * 30 * 32])
    print 'flattened size', flattened.get_shape().as_list()
```

Prints

```
conv size [None, 10, 10, 300, 64]
pool size [None, 5, 5, 150, 64]
conv size [None, 5, 5, 150, 32]
pool size [None, 1, 1, 30, 32]
flattened size [None, 10, 960]
```

But I am getting the error

```
  ARGS.func(ARGS)
  File "cnn_rnn.py", line 274, in train
model.fit(session, saver, train, test)
  File "/Users//Desktop/Coterm/Winter2018/Psych209/Final/neural-transposition-corrector/CNN/rnn_model.py", line 110, in fit
score = self.run_epoch(sess, train, dev)
  File "/Users//Desktop/Coterm/Winter2018/Psych209/Final/neural-transposition-corrector/CNN/rnn_model.py", line 69, in run_epoch
loss = self.train_on_batch(sess, *batch)
  File "cnn_rnn.py", line 211, in train_on_batch
_, loss = sess.run([self.train_op, self.loss], feed_dict=feed)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 889, in run
run_metadata_ptr)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1120, in _run
feed_dict_tensor, options, run_metadata)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1317, in _do_run
options, run_metadata)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1336, in _do_call
raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Input to reshape is a tensor with 30720 values, but the requested shape requires a multiple of 9600
     [[Node: Reshape_1 = Reshape[T=DT_FLOAT, Tshape=DT_INT32, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](max_pooling3d_2/MaxPool3D, Reshape_1/shape)]]

Caused by op u'Reshape_1', defined at:
  File "cnn_rnn.py", line 335, in <module>
ARGS.func(ARGS)
  File "cnn_rnn.py", line 266, in train
model = CNN_RNN(config, embeddings)
  File "cnn_rnn.py", line 225, in __init__
self.build()
  File "/Users//Desktop/Coterm/Winter2018/Psych209/Final/neural-transposition-corrector/CNN/model.py", line 81, in build
  File "cnn_rnn.py", line 109, in add_prediction_op
x = self.convolve(x)
  File "cnn_rnn.py", line 96, in convolve
flattened = tf.reshape(pool2, [-1, 10, 1 * 30 * 32])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_array_ops.py", line 3938, in reshape
"Reshape", tensor=tensor, shape=shape, name=name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 787, in _apply_op_helper
op_def=op_def)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 2956, in create_op
op_def=op_def)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1470, in __init__
self._traceback = self._graph._extract_stack()  # pylint: disable=protected-access

InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): Input to reshape is a tensor with 30720 values, but the requested shape requires a multiple of 9600
     [[Node: Reshape_1 = Reshape[T=DT_FLOAT, Tshape=DT_INT32, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](max_pooling3d_2/MaxPool3D, Reshape_1/shape)]]
```

I understand something is wrong with the dimensions of my call to reshape, but from printing the dimensions of the preceding steps it looks like it should be fine. This is my first time working with conv3d so it's quite possible I'm making a stupid mistake.

Does anyone know what the dimensionality should be?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it! The problem was that the reshape call should've been     flattened = tf.reshape(pool2, [-1, 1, 1 * 30 * 32])